# как вызвать метод одного класса из другого класса

Tags: c++

Необходимо вызвать метод объекта ob2 из метода exe объекта ob1, используя ссылку, находящуюся в векторе объекта ob1

```
class cl_1 {
    vector <cl_1 *> children;
}
class cl_2 : public cl_1
{
    void exe()
    {
/////
    }
}

class cl_3 : public cl_1
{
    void message()
        {
             std::cout <<"Massage";
        }
}

int main()
{
    cl_2 ob1;
    cl_3 ob2;
    ob1.children.push_back(&ob2);
    ob1.exe();
}
```

Comment: `((cl_3 *)children[0])->message();` - Вы делаете программу для массажного кабинета?

Comment: Имеет смысл сделать метод `message` виртуальным.

Comment: void exe()
    {
        ((cl_3 *)children[0])->message();
    }
Должно быть так?

Comment: Лучше уж так: `static_cast<cl_3 *>(children[0])->message();`.

Comment: спасибо, всё понятно